# How to fix NX server after upgrading to Maverick

Tags: 10.10, gnome, nx

I'm using NoMachine NX Free Edition (not FreeNX)

After upgrading Ubuntu from 10.04 to 10.10, applications in remote sessions do not show a window title.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows what might fix it?

I'm running nxserver 3.4.0-14 (x64)

**Update (2010-11-12):** this has been fixed in the latest NX Windows Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have the same problem... There is 2 "solutions" I have found on google for the moment :
- Downgrade the metacity package to metacity_2.30.1-0ubuntu1... (from packages.ubuntu.com)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?goto=newpost&t=1590440

Anyway... I found that NX performances are not as good as on lucid... :(

Comment: Disabling the render extension did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Confirming, upgrading windows nxclient to 3.4.0-10 (from 3.4.0-7 for me; on Windows XP) worked perfectly.
http://www.nomachine.com/download-client-windows.php
Tried all or most of the other fixes and none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the client and installing latest 3.4.0.10 fixed the issue. In my case, the problem was that connecting through NX resulted in windows with invisible window borders, if I calculated the place where the close icon was, the window closed, minimize or maximized.